# Gather Scheduled Task information through powershell v2

Tags: powershell, active-directory, scheduled-tasks, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0

I have a script which gathers Scheduled tasks information searching the AD environment. This script runs perfect on Windows Server 2012 servers (Powershell v4) but I can't make it work on Windows Server 2008 servers (running PS v2). I mention the PS version because I have executed the script on the 2012 server forcing PS to v2 execution, and it didn't work either. So, apparently, it only works on PS v4 (maybe v3, I can't tell... but for sure it won't on PS v2).

I need some help to find out how to modify this script to make it compatible with PS v2. Thanks in advance.

Here the script:

```
$Computers = (get-adcomputer -filter {operatingsystem -like "*server*"}).name
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$Report = @()
foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
    if (test-connection $Computer -quiet -count 1)
    {
        #Computer is online
        $path = "\\" + $Computer + "\c$\Windows\System32\Tasks"
        $tasks = Get-ChildItem -recurse -Path $path -File
        foreach ($task in $tasks)
        {
            $Details = "" | select ComputerName, Task, User, Enabled, Application, Arguments
            $AbsolutePath = $task.directory.fullname + "\" + $task.Name
            $TaskInfo = [xml](Get-Content $AbsolutePath)
            $Details.ComputerName = $Computer
            $Details.Task = $task.name
            $Details.User = $TaskInfo.task.principals.principal.userid
            $Details.Enabled = $TaskInfo.task.settings.enabled
            $Details.Application = $TaskInfo.task.actions.exec.command
            $Details.Arguments = $TaskInfo.task.actions.exec.Arguments

            $Report += $Details
        }
    }
    else
    {
        #Computer is offline
    }
}
$Report |Export-Csv -Path 'c:ScheduledTasks.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

I get this error: The term 'get-adcomputer' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At C:\folder\Search-Tasks-IDs.ps1:1 char:29 + $Computers = (get-adcomputer <<<< -filter {operatingsystem -like "server"}).name + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (get-adcomputer:String) [], CommandNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

---

I have a new version to skip the "get-adcomputer" issue, searching for the servers names in a predefined list:

```
<#
.Synopsis
   PowerShell script to list all Scheduled Tasks and the User ID
.DESCRIPTION
   This script scan the content of the c:\Windows\System32\tasks and search the UserID XML value. 
   The output of the script is a comma-separated log file containing the Computername, Task name, UserID.


Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$VerbosePreference = "continue"
$list = (get-adcomputer -filter {operatingsystem -like "*server*"}).name
#>

$list = Get-Content C:servers.txt
Write-Verbose  -Message "Trying to query $($list.count) servers found in 'servers.txt'"
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$Report = @()

foreach ($server in $list) 
{
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Count 1 -Quiet)
    {
        #Computer is online
        $path = "\\" + $server + "\c$\Windows\System32\Tasks"
        $tasks = Get-ChildItem -recurse -Path $path -File
        foreach ($task in $tasks)
        {
            if ($tasks)
            {
                Write-Verbose -Message "I found $($tasks.count) tasks for $server"
            }

            $Details = "" | select ComputerName, Task, User, Enabled, Application, Arguments
            $AbsolutePath = $task.directory.fullname + "\" + $task.Name
            $TaskInfo = [xml](Get-Content $AbsolutePath)
            $Details.ComputerName = $server
            $Details.Task = $task.name
            $Details.User = $TaskInfo.task.principals.principal.userid
            $Details.Enabled = $TaskInfo.task.settings.enabled
            $Details.Application = $TaskInfo.task.actions.exec.command
            $Details.Arguments = $TaskInfo.task.actions.exec.Arguments

            $Report += $Details
        }
    }
    else
    {
        #Computer is offline
    }
}
$Report |Export-Csv -Path 'c:ScheduledTasks.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

This one runs and creates the csv file, but it only populates the headers ("ComputerName","Task","User","Enabled","Application","Arguments") and the servername.

If I remove this line $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue" the script output shows this error:

Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'. At C:\folder\Search-Tasks-IDs_new.ps1:25 char:58 + $tasks = Get-ChildItem -recurse -Path $path -File <<<< + CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-Content : Access to the path 'C:\' is denied. At C:\folder\Search-Tasks-IDs_new.ps1:35 char:42 + $TaskInfo = [xml](Get-Content <<<< $AbsolutePath) + CategoryInfo : PermissionDenied: (C::String) [Get-Content], UnauthorizedAccessException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentReaderUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Comment: Your CSV path is malformed `Export-Csv -Path 'c:ScheduledTasks.csv'`

Comment: I don't think so. It will create the csv file in the folder from were the script is being run.

Comment: If you've got error messages or extra code you want to add to your question, it's best to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47438576/edit) your question instead of using comments.

Comment: great to know !